# Let admin users edit member profiles from front end

Tags: users, front-end, user-meta, user-registration

I'm using WP User Frontend Pro, but the pro version lacks the feature of letting admins edit registered users profiles from front end.

I'm building a web app using WordPress, and the administrator will not have access to the WordPress Dashboard. I've created the features that I need and put them all on the front-end.
The only user with access to WordPress Dashboard will be the super administrator (me). But I will only manage the system.

The web app administrator will need to edit users from font end.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a plugin with this feature?

I appreciate all help, since this is the last thing I have to do before putting the web app live.

Comment: try posting ur problem in fragments first thing u prolly wanna do is adding a front page by code, which you can do by wp_insert_funciton(); next fetching all your user details from data base and so on ..

Comment: Exactly, that is what I want to do. So my question is: How? I need some help in the correct direction to achieve this.